# How to get an object from a _ref

Tags: rally

I apologize if this is a stupid/newb question, but when a Rally query result is returned with a _ref (using the Javascript SDK 1.32), is there a way to directly get the object associated with the _ref?

I see that I can use getRefFromTypeAndObjectId to get the type and the object ID, and then query on that type and object ID to get the object, however I wondered if there was something like getObjectFromRef or some other such way to more directly get back the object associated with the reference.

Comment: Can you let us know which language/SDK toolkit you are using? I.E. Ruby, .NET, Javascript?

Comment: Sorry - this is using the Javascript SDK (1.32). I will add it to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question.  The getRallyObject method on [RallyDataSource](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rally-data-source) should do what you need.

```
var ref = '/defect/12345.js';
rallyDataSource.getRallyObject(ref, function(result) {
    //got it
    var name = result.Name;
}, function(response) {
    //oh noes... errors
    var errors = response.Errors;
});
```

Comment: Very helpful! Is there an AppSDK2 equivalent to this?

Comment: (See below for SDK 2.0 answer)

Answer (score 1):

In SDK 2.0 you use the load method of a data model to read a specific object.  Check out this example: http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/guide/appsdk_20_data_models